# How do I re-enable the lightdm.service?

Tags: debian, services, cinnamon, lightdm

At some point, in the past, I must have disabled `lightdm` service with:

```
systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

or something similar on my Debian with Cinnamon desktop.

Unfortunately, I will now need it, but running:

```
systemctl start lightdm.service
```

every time the computer boots up does not make me happy, so...

How do I re-enable the `lightdm` service? Because just running:

```
systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

yields to the following error:

```
Synchronizing state of lightdm.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lightdm
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

---

Also tried before:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your service is **masked**.

---

To unmask it, run:

```
systemctl unmask lightdm.service
```

and afterwards, run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: On Debian, the right answer deals in the contents of `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and the `display-manager.service` service.

Comment: @JdeBP `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` = `/usr/sbin/lightdm`, so I think I'm good here, tried running `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` before but with no results, if you mean that...

Answer (score 4):

Enabling the `lightdm.service` unit does nothing for the reason given in the message that is right in front of you: [the service unit](https://sources.debian.org/src/lightdm/1.26.0-6/debian/lightdm.service/) has no `[Install]` information.  This is because one is supposed not to enable this service with `systemctl enable`.  Display managers have their own idiosyncratic enable/disable mechanism.

This service is one of the possible stand-ins for `display-manager.service`, which is a hook for *whatever display manager one chooses to run*.  `display-manager.service` is a symbolic link that is intended to point to whatever the *actual* display manager service unit file is, as the systemd user manual states.  It is a fixed and hardwired `Wants` in the `graphical.target` unit, the idea being that if one starts up with `graphical.target` as the start point of the service graph, one's chosen display manager is started by dint of that.

This symbolic link is of course an ideal opportunity for employing [Debian's "alternatives" system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).  Switching amongst display managers could be a simple and consistent across all packages matter of running:

```
update-alternatives --config display-manager.service
```

This is indeed [how it is done on OpenSUSE](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Change_Display_Manager), albeit that it is not switching a systemd unit around:

```
update-alternatives --config default-displaymanager
```

So *of course* the "alternatives" system is *not* used here; the switching between the possibilities instead being managed by bespoke code in the package maintainer scripts for the [`lightdm`](https://sources.debian.org/src/lightdm/1.26.0-6/debian/lightdm.postinst/#L65), [`gdm3`](https://sources.debian.org/src/gdm3/3.34.1-1/debian/gdm3.postinst/#L43), [`xdm`](https://sources.debian.org/src/xdm/1:1.1.11-3/debian/xdm.postinst.in/#L23), and other packages that reads an idiosyncratic `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file, and does not quite do the same thing in each package.

Once one has run one of these different pieces of bespoke shell scripting, via `dpkg-reconfigure`, one also has to ensure that the start point at bootstrap is the `graphical.target` unit and not the `multi-user.target` unit, with `systemctl set-default`.

Comment: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for display-manager.service`

Answer (score 0):

Lightdm manged by sysV init style startup scripts (debian 8 - 11) via symbolic links at /etc/rc*.d/

(systemd just call it via systemd-sysv-generator)

`update-rc.d lightdm defaults`

Answer (score 0):

Try to temporary install an **alternative Display Manager** like **sddm** and then **switch back to lightdm**. Tested on Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

```bash
sudo apt install sddm # Select sddm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm # Switch back to lightdm
sudo reboot
sudo systemctl status lightdm.service # After reboot, should be active
```

Other usefull commands to debug :

```bash
ls -rtla /var/log/lightdm # see logs files
less +G /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log # see from the end
lightdm --test-mode --debug # test
```