# How do I add a FullHD resolution to my display over TeamViewer?

Tags: xorg, cinnamon, xrandr, intel-graphics, resolution

Since we managed to get my LightDM on Cinnamon DE in Debian Stretch [working at boot again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561798/126755), I installed TeamViewer and am working with the desktop directly, this way is better in order not having to keep open SSH connection, which I doomed just because I need to start up Handbrake for a very long time, as such I deleted [my previous question about flatpak issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561791/how-to-run-flatpaked-handbrake-over-ssh), so what **I need now is better resolution**.

---

I tried running:

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080
```

to no avail.

---

Currently, one monitor is connected to VGA with its native resolution of 1920x1080, but I would like to disconnect it, if possible, but first things first, so:

How do I add a FullHD resolution to my display over TeamViewer?

---

I only managed to find [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227894/126755), which sounds overly complex, is there, I hope, a simpler one?

---

I can only see these resolutions in the Display settings:

[image: display resolutions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the culprit was in ATI drivers:

[`xserver-xorg-video-ati`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/xserver-xorg-video-ati)

which were irrelevant to my hardware as I have a [Xeon E3-1225 v3](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75461/intel-xeon-processor-e3-1225-v3-8m-cache-3-20-ghz.html#tab-blade-1-0-4) CPU, so I removed it, rebooted, and voila:

[image: display modes]